# python, django form duplicates label text

Tags: python, django

As time allows, I am messing around with Django.  I have been paying attention to some tutorials and was following this one today on using `django-widget-tweaks` to add Bootstrap to forms.  It "works" but I just noticed something odd.  I am creating a required "profile" form on User-X's first login.  That model&form have two "address" fields.  The model names them "Address1" & "Address2".  However, when the form is rendered the `label` text for Address2 is "Address1".  The lavel is correct for the Address1 field.

The psrt of the form involved:

```
    ...
    {% for field in profileForm.visible_fields %}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ field.label_tag }}

            {% if profileForm.is_bound %}
                {% if field.errors %}
                    {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {{ error }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                    {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
                {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
            {% endif %}

            {% if field.help_text %}
                <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
...
```

From views.py:

```
...
def create_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass  # does nothing, just trigger the validation
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()

    return render(request, 'MySite/index.html', {'profileForm': form})
...
```

Chrome's Developertools shows the rendered html as:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_Address1">Address1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Address1" maxlength="38" class="form-control" required="" id="id_Address1"></div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_Address2">Address1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Address2" maxlength="38" class="form-control" id="id_Address2"></div>
```

For some reason the label "value" is the same for both fields.

What have I missed?

** Edit ** What I missed was a mislabeled "label" in the form code.  Starred at that a long time and didn't see it.

Comment: What's the code for `ProfileForm`? and which tag you have included to use `render_field`

Comment: Doh! the form was the problem.  I mislabeled the second address line.  Thank you